# Is polymorphic class required for dynamic_cast?

Tags: c++

I've done some searching for this, but just to make sure:

Using `dynamic_cast` to cast a base-class pointer to a derived-class pointer requires the base class to be polymorphic? Otherwise we won't even be able to compile?

Thanks.

Comment: Base class needs to have at least one virtual function for dynamic_cast to work

Comment: Which would make it polymorphic, that's what I thought. Thank you.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it doesn't have to be polymorphic - you can have one class that has a virtual destructor, for example, and that would satisfy the dyamic_cast criteria, but would not satisfy a polymorph class criteria, since there is only a single class with a defined behaviour (of course, it's kind of pointless to use dynamic cast in this case, but that's a slightly different matter)

Comment: I see, so basically at least one method (member function or destructor) must have a "virtual" attached to it.

Comment: Correct, some member function, including destructor or some dummy member needs to be virtual (and defined!) so that the object gets a vtable, which is then used to determine if the class matches or not.

Answer (score 2):

You could use dynamic_cast to cast a derived class to a non polymorphic base class.  But you cannot dynamic_cast a non polymorphic base to a derived class.

The standard explains (§5.2.7):

> (1) The result of the expression dynamic_cast(v) (...)
>
> (5) If T is “pointer to cv1 B” and v has type “pointer to cv2 D” such that B is a base class of D, the result is a pointer to the unique B subobject of the D object pointed to by v.
>
> (6) Otherwise, v shall be a pointer to or a glvalue of a polymorphic type

The polymorphic is meant here in a very humble sense:  "*A class that declares or
inherits a virtual function is called a polymorphic class.*" (§10.3/1).

Answer (score 1):

For Upcasts, the base class type - which is the type of the casted expression - has to be polymorphic, [otherwise you get a compiler error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d66e18798a8c165).
That is because `dynamic_cast` uses RTTI to perform the cast and check whether it is successful or not - and RTTI is only generated for polymorphic types.

`static_cast` on the other hand doesn't check whether the cast is valid; if it isn't, the cast invokes undefined behavior. `static_cast` just adds or subtracts an offset from the pointer (or internal pointer of the reference). `dynamic_cast` does a runtime type check.